# How to watermark animated GIFs and combine 2 ImageMagick commands together?

Tags: windows, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am on a Windows 7 machine using imagemagick from the command line.

The following code works to add watermarks to images:

```
composite                      \
     -watermark 30%            \
     -gravity south            \
      the_watermark.png        \
      pic_to_be_watermaked.png \
      watermark_completed.png
```

Problems are:

- It doesn't work when I try to watermark an animated GIF
- How to use this watermark command in conjunction with the command below?

This command takes all the PNGs inside the folder "static_images" and combines them into an animated GIF. It also makes sure that the image is 350px in width and the height is kept to the proper aspect ratio. It also gives the image some fuzz and sets the speed of the animation to 4 and makes sure it loops infinitely:

```
convert                         \
   -resize 350x350              \
   -fuzz 1.6%                   \
   -delay 4                     \
   -loop 0                      \
    static_images/*.png         \
   -layers OptimizePlus         \
   -layers OptimizeTransparency \
    animated_gif.gif
```

### Questions:

1. How can I combine the watermark command with the one above?
2. How can I get the watermark commmand to work with animated GIFs?

Comment: Also, after telling your OS, it's also interesting to know the (full) output of `convert -version`...

Comment: You'll increase your chances to get a useful answer (for instance from me) tremendously if you'd provide (a link to) your sample images in your question. (I know how to do it, but I'm lacking test images right now -- and you can't expect me to create some just to answer the question...)

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle the output is `Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-1 2012-08-21 http://www.imagemagick.org
copyright...`

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle I'm running it on local host, it's not going to be a web service but rather a way for the web editor to generate GIF content for our site. I uploaded the same images here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/z1lp3a . These are PNG frames from a video.

Comment: This was the *full* version string?! There really is an empty line after `Features:  ` ?? Also, `localhost` is not a Operating System (OS)... Are you running this on Linux, Windows, Mac, or?

Comment: Which one of the PNGs from your linked .zip should take the role of `the_watermark.png`??

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle sorry forgot to upload the watermark. As for the O.S. it's windows 7, I mentioned that in the question. Anyway I have a working solution for the watermarking atleast: `convert animated.gif -coalesce -gravity SouthEast -geometry +5+5 null: watermark.png -layers composite -layers optimize animated.gif`. Still not sure if this can be merged with the command that makes all pngs into a single animated gif however.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the Windows 7 bit... Will you upload the watermark.png somewhere?

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the watermark: http://www.sendspace.com/file/jzt6i6

Comment: BTW, your original watermarking command does not produce a nice result for me (watermark is on, but not readable -- was that the intention?) -- Which relative size should the watermark have in the GIF? Same as in your watermarking command?

Comment: BTW, I'll be away for a few days and will likely not be able to finish this answer before mid next week...

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle I cooked up that watermark quickly just as an example. Haven't gotten around to creating a proper one yet. So it's ok if it's not legible. It would be nice if the watermark can always be 10% in height of the image being watermarked and at the bottom right. I imagine having a giant watermark and scaling it down won't make it look blurry when applied to the image. Anyway don't worry about answering it quickly, I have a working shell script going. It would just be nice to be able to combine the 2 commands into one and possibly reducing file size more but no rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you'd like to see?

[image: Animated GIF with watermark]

The trick is to watermark each PNG source file first, then create the GIF from the watermarked PNGs.

So it's the result of these two commands. First, create the watermarked PNGs:

```
for i in sample_images/000*.png; do   
   convert                                     \
      "${i}"                                   \
      sample_images/the_watermark.png          \
     -gravity south                            \
     -composite                                \
      sample_images/$(basename "${i}")_wm.png;
done
```

Note, I didn't use your exact `composite` command because it didn't create a readable watermark, only some blurring on the meant area...

Second, convert the watermarked PNGs to an animated GIF:

```
convert                         \
   -resize 350x350              \
   -fuzz 1.6%                   \
   -delay 4                     \
   -loop 0                      \
    sample_images/*_wm.png      \
   -layers OptimizePlus         \
   -layers OptimizeTransparency \
    animated_gif.gif
```

Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: I like how small your file size turned out to be!